# Sensitivity characteristics of MQ-7

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, sensor

When we look at the sensitivity characteristic graph of MQ sensors, Let's take MQ-7, which is a log_log graph, we find the definition of R0 at 100ppm, this resistance is defined to be **The sensor resistance at 100ppm CO clean Air**. But we do not find any value of this parameter, since the graph plots the log(Rs/R0),and Rs is a variable resistor (varies between 2 to 20k at 100ppm of CO according to table-c "Sensitivity characteristics").

1. Since we are interested in the variation of sense resistance,and the plot is linear, what is the aim of defining R0 ?
2. How can we extract R0 form the graph ?

In the datasheet graph, 5 plots of log(Rs/R0) at different gases are given and there is an important thing that I want to understand (if we take the example of H2 graph), is it the variation of the sense resistor in presence of only H2 gas? or both H2 and CO gases?

Link to datasheet:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-7.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think R0 *is* Rs in the datasheet, in other words the sensor resistance under 100ppm CO clean air is somewhere between 2kΩ and 20kΩ, depending on the unit you happen to get.

You cannot extract it from the graph since the resistance change is shown relative to whatever R0 happens to be for that particular unit.